# Normal map does not work with tangent shading?

Tags: normal-map

I bake normal map from *Cover1* to *Cover* in Blender (in "Tangent" space). Then applied it to *Cover_normal* object.
Quick render is OK with basic shading, but acting very strange with tangent shading enabled.
[image: Tangent Shading]
[.Blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=44144)

Comment: Do you check *Tangent* in *Shading* rollout to get metallic look or for some other reason ? [Tangent space normal maps](https://www.blender.org/manual//render/cycles/nodes/types/vector/normal_map.html#properties) do not require [Tangent shading](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/properties/shading.html).

Comment: Yeah, enabled it only for the matter of look, but i guess it should work regardless of shading properties.